# Advanced Search Catalog Magento

Tags: magento, search, catalog, advanced-search

Hi everyone I am new to magento can you help me please.
I am trying to add check-boxes to search for multiple categories.

[image screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeNGw.png)

I tried this link:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/search_and_advanced_search/how_to_add_search_by_category_to_advanced_search

The check-boxes is not working, when I tried checked 3 check-boxes it will return only 1 category. Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on line 327 add serialize to the `$_GET` variable

Should look like this:

```
$value = $this->getCatsFromSearchUrl(unserialize($_GET['category']));
```

and this code

```
if (($allConditions) || (isset($values['category']) && is_numeric($values['category']))) {
```

change to

```
if (($allConditions) || (isset($values['category']))) {
```